# Parsing MIME mail, extracting binary attachment and text conversion

Tags: haskell

I started using [mime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime) to parse email and extract attachments.
Anything I did, the binary attachment always got corrupted when I wrote it to disk.
Then I realized that, for some weird reason, all the base64 attachments are already decoded when the message is parsed into data types. That's when my problem starts.

If it is an image, it does not work.
The first thing I did was to convert the extracted Text attachment to ByteString with `TE.encodeUtf8`.
No luck. I tried all `Text.Encoding` functions to convert Text to ByteString - nothing works.
Then for some stupid reason I converted/encoded the extracted text back to base64, then again I decoded it from base64 and it worked this time. Why?

So if I encode the extracted attachment to base64 and decode it back, it works.
`B.writeFile "tmp/test.jpg" $ B.pack $ decode $ encodeRawString True $ T.unpack attachment`
Why? Why simple encoding of Text to ByteString did not work but the above silliness does?

Eventually, I played with it a bit more and got to the point when it works with `Data.ByteString.Char8` like this `B.writeFile "tmp/test.jpg" $ BC.pack $ T.unpack attachment`
So I still have to convert Text to String, then String to ByteString.Char8 and only then it works and I get uncorrupted image.

Can please someone explain all this. Why such a pain with binary image attachment?
Why can't I convert base64 decoded Text to ByteString? What am I missing?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This is the code to extract the attachment as requested.
I thought it was not relevant to text encoding/decoding.

```
import Codec.MIME.Parse
import Codec.MIME.Type
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Text (Text, unpack, strip)
import qualified Data.Text as T (null)
import Data.Text.Encoding (encodeUtf8)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)


data Attachment = Attachment { attName :: Text
                             , attSize :: Int
                             , attBody :: Text
                             } deriving (Show)


genAttach :: Text -> [Attachment]
genAttach m =
  let prs v = if isAttach v
              then [Just (mkAttach v)]
              else case mime_val_content v of
                     Single c -> if T.null c
                                 then [Nothing]
                                 else prs $ parseMIMEMessage c
                     Multi vs -> concatMap prs vs
  in let atts = filter isJust $ prs $ parseMIMEMessage m
     in if null atts then [] else map fromJust atts

isAttach :: MIMEValue -> Bool
isAttach mv =
  maybe False check $ mime_val_disp mv
    where check d = if (dispType d) == DispAttachment then True else False

mkAttach :: MIMEValue -> Attachment
mkAttach v =
  let prms = dispParams $ fromJust $ mime_val_disp v
      Single cont = mime_val_content v
      name = check . filter isFn
        where isFn (Filename _) = True
              isFn _            = False
              check = maybe "" (\(Filename n) -> n) . listToMaybe
      size = check . filter isSz
        where isSz (Size _) = True
              isSz _        = False
              check = maybe "" (\(Size n) -> n) . listToMaybe
  in Attachment { attName = name prms
                , attSize = let s = size prms
                            in if T.null s then 0 else read $ unpack s
                , attBody = cont
                }
```

Comment: Please show some working code. What are your modules `B`, `TE`, `BC`, etc.? Where is `decode` coming from? etc.

Comment: @user5402 The decode comes from the mime package as I mentioned in the post. I did not think the extraction code is somehow relevant to the Text conversion. But I encloded it anyway as requested.

Comment: ok - I've got your code working; now what doesn't work? Can you give a sample MIME message that demonstrates your problem? One thing I noticed is that `parseMIMEMessage` takes a `Text` argument, but a mime message really is a ByteString. There are a bunch of small example mime messages available on this page (near the bottom): https://hunnysoft.com/mime/samples/index.html Does one of those demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @user5402 Now create an email with small jpg image attachment. Parse it, extract the attachment, write it to disk as I mentioned in the post. Then see if the image is not corrupted. The problem is not in parsing/extracting. The problem is in making a valid jpeg after parsing and extracting the attachment. When I write extracted attachment to disk it is an invalid jpg unless I do as described in the post. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 3):

Note that the mime package chooses to represent binary content with a `Text` value. The way to derive the corresponding `ByteString` is to latin1 encode the text. In this case it is guaranteed that all of the code points in the text string will be in the range 0 - 255.

Create a file with this content:

```
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP8AAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==
```

This is the base64 encoding of the 1x1 red GIF image at http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1x1.GIF

Here is some code which uses `parseMIMEMessage` to recreate this file.

```
import Codec.MIME.Parse
import Codec.MIME.Type

import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import System.IO

test1 path = do
  msg <- TIO.readFile path
  let mval = parseMIMEMessage msg
      Single img = mime_val_content mval
  withBinaryFile "out-io" WriteMode $ \h -> do
    hSetEncoding h latin1
    TIO.hPutStr h img

test2 path = do
  msg <- TIO.readFile path
  let mval = parseMIMEMessage msg
      Single img = mime_val_content mval
      bytes =   BS.pack $ T.unpack img
  BS.writeFile "out-bs" bytes
```

In `test2` the latin1 encoding is accomplished with `BS.pack . T.unpack`.

Answer (score 0):

The `mime` package uses `Text` throughout, but undoes any `base64` (or `quoted-printable`) encoding for the bodies of message parts according to their `Content-Encoding` MIME header field.

What this means is that the body of the resulting message part is of type `Text` but (unless the MIME type is `text/*`) this is not an appropriate type as the body should really be a sequence of *bytes*, not *characters*. The characters that it uses are Unicode code points `00` to `FF` which have an obvious mapping onto bytes, but they are *not the same thing*. (Furthermore, if the MIME type *is* `text/*` but the `charset` is not `us-ascii` or `iso8859-1` then I think `mime` will garble the content.)

What I suspect was happening was that you were writing the `Text` out to disk you were using `Data.Text.IO.writeFile` or similar, which uses the character encoding specified in your environment to convert the characters to bytes. Many common character encodings map characters `00` to `7F` onto bytes `00` to `7F` but hardly any map the remaining characters `80` to `FF` onto their corresponding bytes. On many systems these days the environment's encoding is UTF8 which doesn't even map those characters into *single* bytes. (Were the file sizes different from what you expected?)

In order to write it out correctly you needed to convert this characters to the right bytes first. The simplest way to do this is to use the functions in the `Data.Bytestring.Char8` module, which are designed to confuse bytes and characters in exactly this way. But they work on `String`s and not on `Text`s so you have to unpack and repack everything.

I'm not sure how you managed to base-64 encode your `Text` value, as base-64 encoding also operates on bytes and not characters. However you did it, you must have managed to map characters `80` to `FF` onto the corresponding bytes directly rather than encoding them in any way.

If you want to know more, there is a good article on this here: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/